# It's possible to send a dictionary as an argument using subprocess.Popen function?

Tags: python-3.x

I want so send a bash command to my computer since flask using subprocess.Popen function... the file to execute is a python file but it needs three values as arguments, the last value is a dictionary, but subprocess.Popen only accepts str .. is there a way to send this dictionary?

```
myDict = {1:"a",2:"b"}
value1 = "data"
value2 = "data1"

bashCommand = "python script.py " + value1 +" "+value2+" "+myDict
process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, error = process.communicate()
```

bashCommand = "python script.py "+value1+" "+value2+" "+myDict
TypeError: must be str, not dict

Comment: Please, share `script.py` source code. Check what `script.py` does with the last argument - `myDict`. Try to run `python script.py " + value1 +" "+value2+" "+myDict` in bash before trying to run it python. Once you do you'll have a lead on how to run it in python. The only thing that pops to mind is that `{1:"a",2:"b"}` is given as string to `script.py` and there converted to dictionary

Comment: I've checked running the script.py using the console and it works... I turned into the dictionary in json using json.dumps and I sent this as argument and it works. thanks

Comment: ok, if my answer helped you, please accept it

Answer (score 0):

pass dictionary `{1:"a",2:"b"}`  as string to `script.py`.

`Script.py` most probably parses the string into dictionary. For example, using `json` module:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Jul 10 2019, 11:58:48) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import json
>>>  json.loads('{"1":"a","2":"b"}')
{'2': 'b', '1': 'a'}
>>>
```

Comment: I parsed the dict to json using json.dumps() , it turn into the dict in a string, when the script.py receive the string  Im trying to convert the string in a dict but it gets a error

Comment: is it a new problem? if yes, please create new question or edit current question. share the code and error you get